# Convert hexadecimal to decimal number

Tags: lua

Is there a function in Lua which allows to convert a hex number to a decimal number?

Comment: have you tried `google LUA Convert hexadecimal to decimal number`?

Comment: of course... that was the first thing i did, nothing helpful came back

Comment: I got this: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-09/msg00054.html seems to do what you need?

Comment: No? Your link is a function to convert from dec to hex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7165577/.

Comment: @Black oh yes, my mistake, that's a *totally* different problem.

Comment: i still can't convert it, it seems like there is not such a function, so i am forced to write my own

Answer (score 21):

Use `tonumber` to convert from strings to numbers.

Both these print `2014`:

```
print(tonumber("0x7DE"))

print(tonumber("7DE",16))
```

You can also use hexadecimal constants directly:

```
print(0x7DE)
```

Comment: But i need to convert from hex to dec, not from string to number, but thx for your try!

Comment: @Black, if you want a string at the end, do `tostring(tonumber(s,16))`.

Comment: @Ihf, Problem solved, but i had to use tonumber(x,10) instead of 16 :)

tonumber(myhex, 10)

Comment: Ah sorry! I was wrong, i mean tonumber(myhex,16) worked.